# Expecting SIGSEGV , but getting normal working

Tags: c, runtime-error, operator-precedence

I was working on a C output question:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[][2][3]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
   int i=-1;
   int d;
   d=a[i++][++i][++i];
   printf("%d\n",d);
   return 0;
}
```

Link to Ideone: http://ideone.com/1oS9Un

and was expecting a runtime error, but surprisingly the code is working fine on CodeBlocks,Dev C++ and Ideone.

According to me every memory address is resolved by compiler at runtime by the following equation : a[i][j][k]= *(*(*(a+i)+j)+k), thus every compiler should first resolve the inner parenthesis , then the next inner parenthesis and so on.

Thus the given line

```
d=a[i++][++i][++i];
```

should be resolved as:

```
d=*(*(*(a+i++)+ ++i)+ ++i)
```

also by , http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm
          (Please refer note 2)

the innermost parenthesis should be resolved first, and it's value should be a-1 , with i becoming 0. Thus we should get a SIGSEGV error as we are trying to access memory not specifically marked by the compiler, still an output is shown in all the three compilers. Please explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thus we should get a SIGSEGV error

No we shouldn't. If the behaviour is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anything can happen. There is no guarantee of a segfault.

P.S. The behaviour of your code is undefined, but for reasons other than what's stated in the question. The actual reason is that you modify `i` several times between sequence points. See the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/index.html).

Comment: but why is this undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There is no C standard which states anywhere that "if you go out of bounds on an array, then the system must terminate the process at runtime with a segmentation fault (aka. memory access violation)".

C is **not safe** in this sense.  You are free to write erroneous code that may function sometimes and fail in others, because it is erroneous.  The standard is not intended to define what should happen when you go wrong -- it is intended to define what is right, what will happen when things are right, and (generally by implication) what would be *wrong*, but (again) not what should happen when things are wrong.  That would place additional (and arguably very unnecessary) constraints on implementations.

This is why we have the term *undefined behavior*, which I believe was coined for the C standard.  "Undefined" is what happens when you do something that is not covered -- it may still be a logical result sometimes, just you have no guarantee that is will be consistent.